# Configure gremlin-server to use UUID as the id for vrtices and edges

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I'm using apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.10 with the default gremlin-server.yaml

When creating vertices and edges, by default the id is Long and I would like to use UUID instead. I couldn't find a simple and straightforward approach to do so on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using TinkerGraph if you are using the default `gremlin-server.yaml`. That file configured one TinkerGraph at:

```
graph: conf/tinkergraph-empty.properties
```

which should have these contents:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=LONG
```

Change the `vertexIdManager` to "UUID" and restart the server. Please see other TinkerGraph configuration options in the Reference Documentation:

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuration